# Output PHP delimiter (<?php, ?>) without PHP interpreting the delimiters

Tags: php, javascript, interpreter

I run PHP in JavaScript files, e.g....

```
var = '<?php /*some code*/ ?>';).
```

I need to use JavaScript to scan a string for PHP delimiters (the < ? php and ? > that open and close PHP).

I already know the code using JavaScript...

```
if (b.value.indexOf('<?php')>-1) {alert('PHP delimiter found.');}
```

What I'm having trouble with is that I need to keep the ability for PHP to be interpretted in JavaScript files (no exceptions). I simply need to output the delimiter strings to the client in JavaScript and not have them interpreted by the server.

So the final output (from the client's view) would be...

```
if (b.value.indexOf('<?php')>-1) {alert('PHP delimiter found.');}
```

With the following code...

```
if (b.value.indexOf('<?php echo '<?php'; ?>')>-1 || b.value.indexOf('<?php echo '?>'; ?>')>-1)
```

I get the error: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_AND"

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do?

Comment: You might just have a quoting problem in the last example. You are using single quotes to start a javascript string and single quotes to echo the php string. I'm not sure if this is a problem but it could be.

Comment: I'm trying to prevent PHP from being submitted by clients, I already intercept it at the server.

Comment: To add to @TomalakGeret'kal, to me it seems you are trying to do something in a way which is totally more difficult than necessary.

Comment: @John, PHP isn't send to clients at all. Only PHP's output (echo, print, the parts outside `<?php ?>`).

Comment: I've written my own blog, forums, threaded private messaging, control panel, statistics and so forth from SCRATCH without ANY frameworks with LOTS of AJAX using XHTML, CSS, DOM based JavaScript, OOP PHP and normalized relational MySQL - in short I know exactly what I'm asking. This question has been answered by @PaulPRO. Thanks to all that took the time to try and help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of Javascript's ability to parse hex as a character:

```
if (b.value.indexOf('<\x3fphp')>-1) {alert('PHP delimiter found.');}
```

In Javascript `'<\x3fphp'` is exactly the same thing as `'<?php'`, but it has no meaning in PHP.

Comment: This not only worked it did NOT require PHP thus saving even a small amount of server load, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Javascript will never find the `<?php` in your strings because simply, they have already been parsed by your PHP Server. Javascript is a client-side script and is executed after your server-side scripts.

Comment: I program OOP PHP and have advanced understanding of both client and server languages.

Comment: @Pierre -1 (to counter the upvotes) Restating the question isn't an answer.

Comment: @john, sorry, but it doesn't seem like it since you are asking this question. Either contradict me by making your question more clear, or learn from this.

Comment: No problem, I can see how others could interpret this as more of a greenhorn question.

Answer (score 0):

Use output buffering on the PHP, then htmlspecialchars() on the buffered output. You then search for the HTML entities with the JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you however for this specific case I was able to resolve the problem using just JavaScript. Interesting approach though.

Answer (score 0):

the first thing that came into my mind and should work is this simple, little "cheat":

```
<?php echo '<'.'?php'; ?>
```

the php interpreter doesn't see a `<?php`, but the output is as desired.

Comment: Tried that and for some reason it still interpreted (at least in this situation), thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 0):

`<?php echo '<?php'; ?>` ... `<?php echo '?>'; ?>`

Comment: Ah, oezi beat me to it... I'm typing on a mobile phone. no need for string concatenation tho

Comment: Thanks for trying however that was what was being interpreted unfortunately. I also tried to use multiple echos unsuccessfully.